# gives error segmentation fault (core dumped) after giving the correct output

Tags: c++, linux, segmentation-fault

The code given below gives a correct output bus after that prints segmentation fault (core dumped) error. I have got this error a number of times and have tried searching about it but never got a clear idea about it. I used gdb and got the following error:

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000003c0c49d4d1 in std::basic_string, std::allocator >::~basic_string() ()
from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6

where did i try to access an invalid memory address. And if i did how did it give a correct result. I am a novice to unix and c++. Please explain.

Code:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cstring>
 #include <cstdlib>

 using namespace std;

 string convMMDDYY(string str)
 {
          char *dateToConv= new char[str.length()+1];
          strcpy(dateToConv,str.c_str());
          char *ch = strtok(dateToConv,"-");
          string date="";
          string time="";
          while(ch!=NULL)
          {
                date = date + ch[strlen(ch)-2] + ch[strlen(ch)-1] + "/" ;
                ch=strtok(NULL,"-");
          }

          date = date.substr(0,8);

          string convDate = date.substr(3,2) + "/" + date.substr(6,2) + "/" + date.substr(0,2);

          unsigned found = str.find_last_of("-");
          time = str.substr(found+1,8);

          string convFormat = convDate + " " + time;
          cout<<convFormat<<endl;
 }


 int main()
 {
          string a="2014-08-26-22:10:55.452549893";
          convMMDDYY(a);
          return 0;
 }
```

the program inputs date in 2014-08-26-22:10:55.452549893 format and gives output as 08/26/14 22:10:55

and then gives an error Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`convMMDDYY` is declared to return `string` but you do not have any `return` statement, causing undefined behaviour when the function gets to the end.

(You have various other problems, e.g. you never `delete[]` the memory you `new[]`'d, and there is a lack of error checking, so that unexpected inputs cause your code to buffer overflow or access out of bounds of arrays.)

Comment: Something properly enabled compiler warnings would have told the OP about... start with `-Wall -Wextra`, then consult [the manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.1/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options) for what else is available.